# Swift closure strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift-playground

Why does this code compile (in Playground):

```
func text (f: String -> Void) {
    f("text")
}

func foo(s: String) {
    countElements(s)
}

text() {
    s in
        foo(s)
}
```

And this one doesn't:

```
func text (f: String -> Void) {
    f("text")
}

func foo(s: String) {
    countElements(s)
}

text() {
    s in
        countElements(s)
}
```

With error message:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type '(($T3) -> ($T3) -> $T2) -> (($T3) -> $T2) -> $T2'       to type '_BuiltinIntegerLiteralConvertible'
```

I can tell that there is something with return type, kinda Swift thinks that I want to return  int but I just want to print it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second version of the code works if you add an explicit `return` statement:

```
text() {
    s in countElements(s)
    return
}
```

The reason for that to happens is that it uses implicit return, being a single statement closure, so it tries uses the return value of `countElements`, which doesn't match with the expected return type, `Void`. The explicit `return` fixes that.

As to why it behaves in a different way, in the former case `foo` implicitly returns `Void`, which matches the closure return type.

More info: [Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_157)